# How to deploy Mindmeld project with production server mode?

Tags: deployment, production, mindmeld

The documentation explains how to run the service locally, but it does not explain how to deploy to the production server. I tried using a new flask service to call Mindmeld app. Although the service started successfully, it didn't load any data. Can you tell me how to deploy to the production?

[server.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wytbJ.png)

Comment: app.app_manager.parse() method fails at self.nlp.process(query_text=text, allowed_intents=allowed_intents, **nlp_params), but there is no error message.

Comment: Could you please provide code instead of image of code.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, the code is in the server.py of Mindmeld.